# ios: Firebase config in workspace with many cocoa framework

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have pod workspace with 1 application and many cocoa touch framework.
I add `FirebaseApp.configure()` into AppDelegate in application.
Then I call firebase func inside my framework and it crash.

> The default Firebase app instance must be configured before the default Firebase Vision instance can be initialized

If I call `FirebaseApp.configure()` again in my framework, it not crash.

Is there's a way I only config firebase once?

My sample project: https://github.com/linhCrystal/TestWorkspace

You can see it crash because Firebase is not config in Feature framework

Comment: did you import firebase to the AppDelegate file?

Comment: @matthew-xavier-jacome yes. I build success but it crash.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: The default Firebase app instance must be configured before the default Firebase Vision instance can be initialized

Comment: Add a break point to any firebase related code recently added. The most probable error you have is that you initialized a firebase object that hasn't been configured in firebase webpage dashboard.

Comment: Here my sample project: https://github.com/linhCrystal/TestWorkspace.

Comment: You can see I comment `FirebaseApp.configure()` in ViewController and it crash